# Перевод текстового файла из UNIX в DOS

Tags: c++

Написать программу, переводящую текстовый файл в из формата UNIX в формат DOS, то есть добавляющую после каждого символа перевода строки (код 10) символ возврата каретки(код 13). Имя файла вводится в командной строке. Язык C++

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char ch;
    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    fp = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("file2.txt", "w");
    while ((fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch)) != EOF) {
        fprintf(fp2, "%c", ch);
        if ((int) ch == 10) {
            fprintf(fp2, "%c", (char) 13);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

Comment: А что вы сами пробовали? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: не могу добавить код для ввода в командной строке для имени файла

Comment: если я правильно понял вам нужно ввести в консоле "имя_прогри адрес_файла"
[описание argc и argv][1]


  [1]: http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/06/0604.htm

Comment: @rafael: вам нужно вот что:

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        if (argc < 2)
        {
            // мало аргументов, ругаемся и выходим
            // или берём файл по умолчанию
        }
        // тут параметр ком. строки в argv[1]

Comment: @rafael Файлы лучше открывать в режимах "wb" и "rb". Если Вы работаете не под виндами разницы нет, а если под виндами -- там идёт преобразование <LF> -- <CR><LF>. И вместо громоздких fprintf и fscanf при посимвольном чтении/записи лучше использовать fputc/fgetc

Comment: http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html вот православная версия того что вам нужно.

Comment: @igumnov: я думаю, автору вопроса нужно научиться работать с комстрокой в C++ -- об этом и его вопрос, исходя из дискуссии в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

Аргументы берутся из параметров функции main. Например, вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        cerr << "need file names as arguments" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // пользуемся советом @alexlz
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb"), *fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (!fp || !fp2) {
        cerr << "cannot open one of the files" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    char ch;
    while ((fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch)) != EOF) {
        if ((int)ch == 10) { // изменил порядок, спасибо @avp
            fprintf(fp2, "%c", (char) 13);
        }
        fprintf(fp2, "%c", ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Кстати, на C++ лучше пользоваться более новыми интерфейсами к файловой системе: `ifstream` и `ofstream`.

Comment: 1. Условие 


     if (!fp || !fp2)

лучше переписать так

    if ( !(fp && fp2))

2.А что если конец строки уже имеет Windows-style?

Comment: @mikillskegg: 1. мне кажется, вопрос вкуса. Вы читаете код как "если не оба файла в порядке", я же как "если первый не в порядке или второй не в порядке". 2. По условию, он unix-style. 3. Проблема ОПа была в передаче параметров из ком. строки, я проиллюстрировал только её решение, остальной код почти не менял. (Я бы вообще переписал на *fstream, C++ всё-таки.)

Comment: @VladD, fprintf-ы определенно надо поменять местами. Зачем тут нужен `iostream` и `using namespace` совершенно непонятно.

Кроме того, IMHO `fprintf()` и `fscanf()` здесь излишни. Более просто и эффективно так:


    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
      if (ch == '\n')
 fputc('\r',fp2);
      fputc(ch,fp2);
    }

@mikillskegg, 2) (уже имеет Windows-style?) - это правильное замечание. IMHO надо добавить к аргументам флаг, запрещающий добавлять `'\r'` перед `"\r\n"`.

Думаю, реализацию можно оставить автору для тренировки.

--

И еще одно. Берите stdin/stdout если файлов нет.

Comment: @avp: насчёт порядка вывода -- спасибо! iostream и std нужны для cerr :) я специально не менял стиль ТС, ведь обсуждение, если посмотреть комментарии к вопросу, идёт вокруг передачи параметров.

Comment: @VladD а чем же Вам stderr-то не угодил?

Comment: @alexlz: не по-плюсовски это как-то. только cout, только fstream, только string, только vector, только хардкор! :D

Comment: @alexlz: (там комментарии закончились). Исторически вы правы, сейчас же по факту формат plain text устройство-независимый. Да и странно было бы, согласитесь, 21 век, интернет и гетерогенные системы на дворе.

Comment: Ну вот и ладушки. Что-то осталось, но глубоко спрятано в каких-то специализированных вещах, типа СУБД. Но какого же члена мне тут пишут по "формат" и вред лишних возвратов каретки? (Кстати, насчёт формата -- у меня перед глазами частенько vim, который умеет работать с концами строк `\n` -- (ff=unix), `\r\n` -- dos, `\r` -- mac)

Comment: @alexlz, вообще-то (IMHO) формат текстового файла вещь не определенная, понимается, скорее, интуитивно. Поэтому в одном из комментариев я предлагал добавить к аргументам программы флаг, который бы специфицировал, как перекодировать - все '\\n' в пару '\\r\\n' или только те, перед которыми уже нет '\r'.

Согласитесь, если говорить о файле с текстом, который периодически обрабатывается *разными* программами то в \*nix, то винде, то хотелось бы, чтобы концы строк были сделаны "правильно" для каждой из систем, а "лишних" символов не появлялось.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой код с учетом возможности того, что входящий файл будет уже иметь Windows-style окончания строк

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        fputs ("Too few arguments\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;    
    }

    FILE* infile = fopen (argv[1], "rb");
    if (infile == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Input file \"%s\" was not opened: %s\n", argv[1], strerror (errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }

    FILE* outfile = fopen (argv[2], "wb");

    if (outfile == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Output file \"%s\" was not opened: %s\n", argv[2], strerror (errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    }

    char ch, tmp;

    while ((ch = fgetc (infile)) != EOF) {
        fputc (ch, outfile);    
        if (ch == '\n') {
                if ((tmp = fgetc (infile)) != '\r') {
                fputc ('\r', outfile);      
            }
            ungetc (tmp, infile);           
        }
    }

    fclose(infile);
    fclose (outfile);
}
```

Comment: @mikillskegg, в DOS/Windows строки завершаются `"\r\n"`, **а не `"\n\r"`**, как почему-то все здесь пишут.

Для того, чтобы не удваивать `'\r'`  заглядывание вперед с последующим ungetc() не нужны. Достаточно просто всегда запоминать предыдущий символ и соответственно анализировать его когда прочитали `'\n'`.

Comment: Ну да, если \r\n, то ungetc просто не нужен. Ответ пока удалю, перепишу завтра, если будет время. 

Однако, если бы нужно было заменить на  \n\r, есть какие-то замечания?

Comment: Если на \\n\\r, то так логично, ungetc() нужен. Хотя, можно подумать...

Если всегда читать "на символ вперед" (т.е. выводить предыдущий, а самый последний уже после EOF), то вроде ungetc() тоже не нужен.

Попробую завтра.

Comment: Да можно было бы и без ungetc, но получилось бы более громоздко. А так просто и без хитростей.

Comment: @mikillskegg: для \n\r без ungetc было бы так: http://pastebin.com/fbVLF71R

Comment: @VladD, точно, это (`checknext = ch == '\n';`) Вы здорово придумали, тут достаточно одного считанного символа.

У меня с 2-мя (текущий и предыдущий символы) на 3 строчки больше.

Comment: @avp: спасибо! (покраснел)

Comment: @avp: вот должно быть ещё короче: http://pastebin.com/S5kvr22n

Поправка: то есть http://pastebin.com/kjK4hJc2

Comment: А чем опасно удвоение `\r`? Ну будет `\r\r\n` и что? Смысл `\r` -- на построчных принтерах сделать повторную печать в той же строке. '\r\n' в unix-файле штука довольно бессмысленная, но не вредная. Так же как и `\r\r\n`. Или это оптимизация для экономии места на диске?

Comment: @avp не понял EOL -- это `\n` (0x0A в ASCII). И что?

Comment: @alexlz, смысл (логика данных) теряется. Строка - это байты, завершающиеся EOL.

В Unix EOL == '\n', а в Дос и Винде это пара байт \r\n.

Содержимое строки, очевидно, обычно менять не надо.

--

У меня комментарии кончились. Пришлось удалить-добавить, поэтому комментарий переполз.

--

@alexlz,  **EOL** это я так записал понятие "КонецСтроки". Думал понятно будет, что не обязательно \\n, который, кстати, в таблице ASCII обозван символами **`LF`**

Почему нехорошо удваивать \\r я уж и не знаю, что еще сказать.

Comment: @alexlz: если у вас лишние `\r`, вы нарушаете _формат_! Ведь plain text -- не бесформатная штука: это последовательность символов с кодом >= 0х20, разделённая маркерами конца строки (например, `\r\n`). (Ещё возможны какие-нибудь `0x8` (имеющие специальное значение), но не, например, `0х0`.) Лишний `\r` не вписывается в эту схему, и программы имеют право не воспринять файл как текстовый.

Comment: Мрак и ужас. Были времена, когда информация выводилась на посимвольные (типично -- пишмаш и др.) устройства. В этих устройствах `\r` возвращал каретку в начало строки, `\n` осуществляло протяжку бумаги. В unix `\n` использовали для конца строки, оставив преобразование драйверу. В CP/M, которая выполнялась на микроЭВМ (i8080A и выше, и ниже) драйвер так не нагружали. Этим озадачивали программу (или рантайм для ЯВУ). MS DOS, как наследница CP/M это сохранила. Хотите посмотреть на различные форматы -- посмотрите доки RMS-11 (для систем на pdp-11 или VAX VMS-11). Вот уж где глаза разбегаются.